# What if I have deleted the recovery partition mistakenly?

Tags: laptop, sony-vaio, windows-7-restore, recovery-partition

I am a bit anxious that I might have deleted the recovery partition mistakenly. What should I do if that has happened? How to make sure whether that's the case and the reason I've been unable to use recovery options to restore my laptop to its factory condition?

Answer (score 0):

For being sure, you can try the hotkey at boot. Also you can check your partitions on your OS's disk manager.

In case you deleted, you have options;

- creating recovery disk by pre-installed **recovery disk creator app** on your OS,
- ordering recovery media from your hardware vendor,
- installing fresh OS by genuine OS DVD/CD and your hardware drivers from your vendor's web site (sometimes hard to find genuine OS medias)